# Cant pass FormData to fetch's put request

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, fetch-api, form-data

So I'm using github/fetch to make xhr calls to my API. Post and get are working fine, but seems like put calls won't pass the FormData properly.

They are passed as form-data in my xhr call. This should be x-www-urlencoded. When I encode my url with the data everything is working fine.

I'm setting the type like this:
`options.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';`

What could this be?

Comment: Try to remove the `Content-Type` header.